# Is it possible to implement the CVXPY library on a Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, installation, cvxpy

I would like to implement a MPC controller on a RPI3, but my script uses CVXPY, and I have some trouble installing it. When I search the internet, I do not find anyone else who has done it, so now I am thinking it might not be possible to do it? can anyone tell me if it is possible and if it is, how to do it :)

Best Regards

Comment: At Mosek we have been working on Rashberry PI 3 port. So we could potentially help you if you would use Mosek using one of our interfaces.

Comment: Hi Erling, if your interface could help solve the optimization for the MPC I would like to use it.

Comment: Our parametric Fusion is ideal for that. I suggest you try it out on X86 and then contact support@mosek.com when you want to try AARCH64. See  https://themosekblog.blogspot.com/2020/03/parametrized-fusion-benchmarks.html